# ERD database relationship 1 to many or many to many

Tags: database, erd

I've two tables and I'm confused if it's going to be a 1 to many or many to many relationship.

```
event
-------------------------
id | name 
-------------------------

day
-------------------------
id | name | event_id
-------------------------
```

I'll be managing several events in this app, Basically an event comprises of some number of days, and each day in turn have sessions where speaker speaks on (not mentioned in above structure).

My question is, the relationship between event and day should be 1 to many or many to many?

Should I take this as it is or shall I introduce another table `event_day` (the days are unique to the event and can't be associated to another event)

The phrase that many events has many days is true in the above case that's what confused me for many to many relationship.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a day can only have 1 event then you have a 1-to-many relationship.

I tell-tale sign of this is the foreign_key `event_id` on the day table. If your example captures all the data you need, 1-to-many is the way to go.

If I were you I'd call this model EventDay, just for clarity. I don't like using terms like Day that are heavily overloaded.

Comment: even if `day` is associated to 1 and only 1 `event`, i.e. this specific day can't be associated to another event? Just like day has many sessions but each session is associated to only 1 and one `day`, is day and session also many to many?

Comment: No, if a day can only have 1 event then you don't need the join table. Updating my answer...